# Isn't got anyway to convert my website image become dual language?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I already add google translate tools in my website, but once I translate , only content will translated, I know just create another HTML file which is convert all content and image become dual language , so what I want to know isn't got anyway to convert my website **image** become dual language?

my website code language : HTML, CSS, javascript, php

my website link: http://www.ezyfax.com/

Comment: If you're looking for an IMAGE language translation system... Maybe you could start one.

Comment: if this is a business side, pay the money for real translation and build a language version. Nothing worse for a company than automatically translated content... and it would solve your image issue, too

Answer (score 1):

Since the text embedded in the image, you would not be able to convert the language/text at this point.

What you could perhaps do is to update the images so that they don't have text. Then you can insert the text during run time. You could do this during run time by using imagemagik or gd2 (which probably wouldn't scale well) or you can generate the text and then use CSS to inser the image as a background.

Comment: +1'ed, if gd slows downs page response too much one just needs to cache the generated images.